# Remove a module from the configuration even if its cached

Tags: php, magento, caching

I have a site where I am running multiple stores within magento and need to disable modules on per store level.

The second answer here [Magento: Disable module for any particular store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962066/magento-disable-module-for-any-particular-store) does work, however the layout cache will need to be turned off. Which seems to dramatically increase server load.

I found this article by alan storm which seems like it would be helpful http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_a_critique_and_caching

Is there a way I can strip a particular piece of the xml even when its being loaded from cache?

This seems like it will be hacky no matter how it's implemented, but a majority of the extensions writers don't seem take the multi website/store into account when building their extensions. It would be nice to be able to completely disable a module per store and still allow the layout cache to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I figured this one out.

in /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php (copy of original).

```
   public function loadModulesCache()
{
    if (Mage::isInstalled(array('etc_dir' => $this->getOptions()->getEtcDir()))) {
        if ($this->_canUseCacheForInit()) {
            Varien_Profiler::start('mage::app::init::config::load_cache');
            $loaded = $this->loadCache();
            Varien_Profiler::stop('mage::app::init::config::load_cache');
            if ($loaded) {


               ***PUT CODE HERE TO EDIT $this->_xml***
               Just remove the nodes which should be disabled.


                $this->_useCache = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way or if this should even be done, but I am going to test now and see if any other errors pop up