# How to disable extension for a particular extension in magento?

Tags: magento

I am overiding the deafult `onepage_payment_methods` in my custom extension.
I want to disable the extension fully (not only output) for particular store.  Please guide as I am new to Magento.

Comment: @Raptor: that's not a valid close reason. If the question is off-topic here we can migrate it, but *first determine that it is off-topic here*, i.e. it doesn't fit the normal on-topic rules.

Comment: I have created a custom payment method extension in my multi store application. I want to disable this extension for store 2. When I disable it from from system->config->advanced for store 2, I doesn't get payment methods on checkout page.  I want to , when I disable this extension for a particular store, it should call the default behavior of magento.

Answer (score 1):

Magento modules are enabled/disabled by a line in their `.xml` module control file found in `app/etc/modules`

To completely disable the module, find the `.xml` file named for the module (example `DeveloperName_ModuleName.xml`) and change the following line:

```
<active>true</active>
```

to

```
<active>false</active>
```

Watch for dependencies and if you are looking for specific Magento modules, most will be found in `Mage_All.xml`, other standalone modules will be found in `Mage_xxxxxxxx.xml`. Be aware that turning off certain Mage modules will have knock-on effects and disabling Mage_Core turns Magento off.

[StackExchange question on disabling a module on the store level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962066/magento-disable-module-for-any-particular-store)

Comment: Side note on that excellent answer, if, for some reason, you want to disable ALL your local modules, there is a node in `app/etc/local.xml` that just does that, and it is `<disable_local_modules>`

Comment: <active>false</active> This will deactivate the my extension for all stores.I want to deactivate my custom payment method extension only for single  store in my application.

Comment: Inchoo had an article on doing a per website deactivation. You have to create a module to do it => http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-activatedeactivate-magento-module-per-a-website-level/ Also a question over here on StackExchange => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962066/magento-disable-module-for-any-particular-store

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your admin section than login to your backend, system- configuration->advance -> advance search your extension name and disable it.

Hope it works

Comment: This disables output, doesn't turn off module loading.