# Magento load modules by website/store

Tags: php, magento, caching

I'm working on a webiste that has one store already live and I'm trying to make the second store/website working.

The new website has a template that includes some observers that even if I disable the modules through **System -> Configuration -> Advanced** as this this only *Disable Modules Output* not the actual module, therefore if there are any Observers they will still be loaded and will run.

Searched online and didn't found a complete solution for this. On [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962066/magento-disable-module-for-any-particular-store/) the user [Eric Hainer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442345/eric-hainer) proposed a solution to that allows to load modules depending checking the $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] variable but this does not work if you have cache active as when you load the store that has the modules in it will put them in the cache.

So my solution was to modify the file
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php to save the cache on different folders depending on the store

First I copied the file to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php to avoid changing a core file

and on the constructor added this lines

```
//custom code to save cache on different folders per website
$runCode = (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'default');
$this->_data['cache_dir']   = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'cache'.$runCode;
```

Here is how the constructor looks like

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $appRoot= Mage::getRoot();
    $root   = dirname($appRoot);

    $this->_data['app_dir']     = $appRoot;
    $this->_data['base_dir']    = $root;
    $this->_data['code_dir']    = $appRoot.DS.'code';
    $this->_data['design_dir']  = $appRoot.DS.'design';
    $this->_data['etc_dir']     = $appRoot.DS.'etc';
    $this->_data['lib_dir']     = $root.DS.'lib';
    $this->_data['locale_dir']  = $appRoot.DS.'locale';
    $this->_data['media_dir']   = $root.DS.'media';
    $this->_data['skin_dir']    = $root.DS.'skin';
    $this->_data['var_dir']     = $this->getVarDir();
    $this->_data['tmp_dir']     = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'tmp';
    //custom code to save cache on different folders per website
    $runCode = (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'default');
    $this->_data['cache_dir']   = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'cache'.$runCode;
    $this->_data['log_dir']     = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'log';
    $this->_data['session_dir'] = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'session';
    $this->_data['upload_dir']  = $this->_data['media_dir'].DS.'upload';
    $this->_data['export_dir']  = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'export';
}
```

This will do the job but there are some issues:

- Clear cache will probably not work
- Updates will not be applied automatically as we copied this files from core

Is there any other way to do this?

This post [continues here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040490/magento-load-modules-by-website-store-part-2)

Comment: This has another issue, if your default store (the one that accesses the admin area) has the modules disabled they will not show up to configure in the admin area. 

Making this a not so good solution

Answer (score 0):

Disable the module output per store in the backend under advanced. Then edit your module observer functions and check for that configuration to disable the complete module functionality:

```
if(Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('advanced/modules_disable_output/YOUR_MODULE'))
    return false;
```

Most community modules already have it's own configuration to enable/disable functionality per store.